# App not displaying properly on iphone6

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am having an issue with running my project on the device. Here are two pictures. The first one shows what the project looks like when I run it on the simulator. The second one is the same project run on the device:

[image: On the simulator]

[image: On the device]

As you can see in the first screenshot, I am using Auto Layout and Size classes. On the attributes Inspector I have the size set to iPhone 4.7-inch, but if I set to to "inferred" the same thing happens. I have done a fair bit of research on the web to see if I can find the solution but to no avail. I am fairly new so it could be something simple. Any help appreciated.

Update: I have set the size to inferred and turned off size classes and auto layout and I had resize all the buttons from 100 pixels to 80 pixels and now it looks fine on the device but I get the opposite problem on the simulator which was fine then. Is this an issue to do with iPhone 6 plus?

See next screenshot. On the left the storyboard and on the right the simulator.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set attribute for it..? Because you are using size class. [image: Do this for all object]

Check it. If not set then set it for all objects.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am fairly new to this and teaching myself, so please bear with me. If I disable the size classes the same thing happens.

Comment: Turn of size class and set iphone size inferred not 4.7. I think it will solve the problem

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have tried this and when i set the sized to inferred the app displays wrongly not only on the device but on the simulator too.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am saying is that it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: 1. Select The Size Inspector and remove the auto resizing. it will solve the issue. do it for all your objects which are in the View.
2. Also Uncheck the auto layout for the MainView

Comment: Ok I have done this and I had to resize all my elements in the storyboard. Now the app runs fine on the device (before it was bigger than the screen) BUT now the app is too small on the simulator. It seems that I can't win.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of it..??

Comment: I have updated the question with an extra screenshot.

Comment: I have made a bit of progress. The story board is inferring an iPhone 5s screen size I am not sure why but people are saying it's to do with launch images.

Comment: Hi sorry I appreciate you are trying to help, but I am not sure what you are saying. The picture you have posted corresponds to the size inspector of the image, what you suggest I do with it?

Comment: Remove all red lines (given in auto resizing) . For all sub objects of your View.. Understand..??

Comment: Just done it, it doesn't do anything. I really do appreciate your help. I have been looking on S.O all day and found many different answers none of which are helping so far.